# find record by Id and another Id in a list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb, crud-repository

I have a `CrudRepository` that look like this:

```
public interface MyDocumentRepository extends CrudRepository<MyDocument, String> {}
```

In my object MyDocument I have:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "MyDocument ")
public class MyDocument {

   @DynamoDBHashKey
   private String id;

   @DynamoDBAttribute
   private List<String> anotherIds;
   ...
}
```

I tried to get all documents by id1 that equal to id and by id2 that can be contains anotherId:

```
List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIdContains(String id, String anotherId);
```

But this not work with me and I get this error:

```
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.String and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I tried many ways but all them return this error:

```
List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIdsContains(String id, List<String> anotherId);
List<MyDocument> findByIdAndAnotherIdsContains(String id, List<String> anotherId);
List<MyDocument> findByIdAndAnotherIdsContains(String id, String anotherId);
List<MyDocument> findByIdAndAnotherIdsContaining(String id, String anotherId);
List<MyDocument> findByIdAndAnotherIdsContaining(String id, List<String> anotherId);
```

Any idea how can I do this without `@Query` please?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```java
List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIds(String id, List<String> anotherIds);
```

`Containing` keyword is used to check Strings and reads as "LIKE %*argument*%" in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bu I get the same error `class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.String and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Comment: Can you please try `List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIds(String id, List<String> anotherIds);` or `List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIdsIn(String id, List<String> anotherIds);` with the list containing only the desired ID?

Comment: thank you `List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIds(String id, List<String> anotherIds);` works fine, but If I pass all elements of `AnotherIds` but in my case I want any one

Comment: Not sure if I understood your comment. Doesn't it work if you create a list with only one "anotherId" as a parameter of `findAllByIdAndAnotherIds` method? What about  `findAllByIdAndAnotherIdsIn`?

Answer (score 1):

First things first. You have a field on your entity that is of type `List<String>`. This is not a primitive column on your table. It should at least be annotated with `@ElementCollection`. I also see you miss the `@Id`.

```
public class MyDocument {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @ElementCollection
   private List<String> anotherIds;
}
```

Then you can try again with

`List<MyDocument> findAllByIdAndAnotherIds(String id, String anotherId);`

Comment: thank you for your answer, in fact I use DynamoDBTable I changed my question for more detail